# problema com integração com affinityassistencia (curl + php + xml)

Tags: php, xml, libcurl

pois bem eu to com o curl instalado e funcionando.
Estou tentando fazer a integração com o site:
https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/exemplos/?usuario=teste&senha=teste&button=Entrar
metodo getplanos.

eu envio o xml via curl e retorna que os parametros não foram informados

Nome: GetPlanos (disponivel)

Finalidade:Retornar todos os planos disponiveis.

Parâmetos de requisição:    Login, senha

Parâmetos de resposta:  Código do plano, nome do plano

exemplo: https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/exemplos/getPlanos.asp

```
$input_xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<requisicao>
    <login>xml28</login>
    <senha>15028</senha>

</requisicao>";

$url = 'https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/getPlanosLista/';

  //setting the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// Following line is compulsary to add as it is:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array('Content-type: application/xml',
                'Content-length: '. strlen($input_xml)) );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
                 $input_xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "xml28:15028");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    //convert the XML result into array
//        $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($data)), true);

    print_r('<pre>');
    print_r($data);
    print_r('</pre>');
```

E então alguem tem alguma sugestão?
Att Gustavo

Answer (score 2):

Tem vários erros no código, *mas acredito que deve ter sido suas tentativas de encontrar uma correção*. Sua pergunta está bem vaga, sem documentação exata, mas vamos por partes, *como dizia o Jack*.

---

**TL;DR:**

Faça um GET usando o parametro `mensagem`, ou seja:

```
https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/getPlanosLista/?mensagem='.urlencode($input_xml)
```

---

Usando o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` você vai fazer um *POST* (e não um *GET*). Porém você diz que quer usar o endpoint de "GetPlanos", se o nome tem GET, porque está fazendo um POST?!

1. Use `GET`.

   - Remova o `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.
   - Remova o header de `Content-length`.

Agora precisamos saber o que porque do `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, isso é feito para login usando o *HTTP Authentication*, *isto é aquelas campos de login/senha que aparecem dentro de um alert, provavelmente já viu algum por aí*. :P

2. Remova o `CURLOPT_USERPWD`.

Temos uma informção inexistente. Qual o nome do parametro que deve ser enviado, exemplo `site.com?x=y`, nós temos o *y* mas não temos o *x*.

Vamos fazer uma analise na página enviada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3. Utilize `mensagem` para enviar o XML, *enquanto o `chave` muda a cada sessão, logo não parece ser importante*.

---

No final:

```
// Sua chave:
$parametrosURL['chave'] = '0';

// Sua mensagem:
$parametrosURL['mensagem'] = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<requisicao>
    <login>xml28</login>
    <senha>15028</senha>
</requisicao>";

$parametrosURL = http_build_query($parametrosURL);

$url = 'https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/getPlanosLista/?'.$parametrosURL;

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-type: application/xml']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

print_r('<pre>');
print_r($data);
print_r('</pre>');
```

---

Se a chave não for importante, pode utilizar o exemplo mencionado lá em cima:

```
$mensagem = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
    <requisicao>
        <login>xml28</login>
        <senha>15028</senha>
    </requisicao>";

$url = 'https://www.affinityassistencia.com.br/ws/getPlanosLista/?mensagem='.urlencode($mensagem);
```